# Compile .ts file but don't copy it to `outDir`

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a `config.ts` file in project root, which obviously is not part of the `src` folder.
I want all my `ts`files in folder `src` to be compiled and copied to the `outDir`. This works.

**Question:**
I want to compile-only the `config.ts` and not copy it to `outDir`, because it's only a dev dependency and not part of my app.

**tsconfig.json**

```
 "outDir": "dist", /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
 "rootDir": "./src", /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways you could do this but none of them are very convenient. I suspect it would be easier to just put it alongside the rest of the source files but exclude it from whatever deployment system you use

Comment: Not possible ootb? This should be a feature imo. Ok, let's write a plugin/task then :-)

Comment: It's possible but you'll need to invoke the compiler twice. Once for your source and once for your config.

Comment: Another issue with that is, that I get `TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set' /'Map'., if the `.ts` file is not under folder `src`. It's not a problem if the `config.ts` is part of the `src` folder

Comment: The reason for that is that, by implication, setting the root dir, scopes the configuration to the indicated location. So whatever target or lib configuration doesn't apply to something above it. That's also one of the reasons that providing this behaviour would be hard. It changes things like module resolution completely

Comment: You'll definitely want to look into configuration inheritance.

Comment: I will check out `configuration inheritance`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @AluanHaddad You can post it as an answer if you like, I will accept it!